# C/C++: Constant array of constant arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, constants

What would be the syntax for creating a constant array of constant arrays?

I am wanting a function argument to be a constant array of constant `char*` strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do this by putting `const` on the right of the first asterisk, e.g.

```
void f(const char *const *argument)
```

or equivalently

```
void f(const char *const argument[])
```

For more dimensions, simply add more `*const`s (I would not use the `[]` alternative in this case):

```
void f(const char *const *const *argument) // 2D array of strings
```

Comment: alright, thanks... but wouldn't it be more clear to have the asterisks like this `const char* const* argument`?

Comment: No.  That style is misleading and harmful.  It gives the impression that asterisks bind to the left, when actually they bind to the right.

Answer (score 4):

The key to this is to write the C++ backwards (right to left):

```
         char * const myVar[10] const;
```

...which says that myVar is an const array length 10 of const pointer to char.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that would be a

```
const char* const array[size][size] = { /* initializer */ }
```

That is, an array of arrays of immutable pointers to characters that can't be changed.

Answer (score 2):

The question is a bit unclear: Do you want to *create* (define) an array, or *pass* it to a function?

The syntax to *define* a constant array of constant *C-strings* is

```
const char array[2][14] = { "first string", "second string" };
```

To define a constant array of constant arrays of non-string type, the initializer differs:

```
const int array[2][3] =
{
  { 1, 2, 3 },
  { 4, 5, 6 }
};
```

(If it's appropriate, you should make the array `static const`.)